# Generate Image as byte[] in WinRT with SharpDX

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, sharpdx

I'm trying to generate a simple image and display it in WinRT/XAML.
For that I want the byte[] of an image drawn with SharpDX.
My Approach so far seems fine but the resulting buffer is empty.

I tried CopyPixels as well but it also only produced zeros.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

---

```
    private static byte[] Draw(TexRenderer trnder, int width, int height)
    {
        var wicFactory = new ImagingFactory();
        var dddFactory = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory();
        var dwFactory = new SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory();

        var wicBitmap = new Bitmap(
            wicFactory,
            width,
            height,
            SharpDX.WIC.PixelFormat.Format32bppBGR,
            BitmapCreateCacheOption.CacheOnLoad);


        var renderTargetProperties = new RenderTargetProperties(
            RenderTargetType.Default,
            new SharpDX.Direct2D1.PixelFormat(Format.Unknown, AlphaMode.Unknown),
            dddFactory.DesktopDpi.Width,
            dddFactory.DesktopDpi.Height,
            RenderTargetUsage.None,
            FeatureLevel.Level_DEFAULT);
        var renderTarget = new WicRenderTarget(
            dddFactory,
            wicBitmap,
            renderTargetProperties)
            {
                TextAntialiasMode = TextAntialiasMode.Cleartype
            };

        renderTarget.BeginDraw();

        var textFormat = new TextFormat(dwFactory, "Consolas", 48)
            {
                TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                ParagraphAlignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center
            };
        var textBrush = new SolidColorBrush(
            renderTarget,
            Color.Blue);

        renderTarget.Clear(Color.White);
        renderTarget.DrawText(
            "Hi, mom!",
            textFormat,
            new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height),
            textBrush);
        var bitmapRenderTarget = new BitmapRenderTarget(renderTarget, CompatibleRenderTargetOptions.None);
        trnder.Render(bitmapRenderTarget, 0, 0);

        renderTarget.EndDraw();

        var bitmaplock = wicBitmap.Lock(null, BitmapLockFlags.Read);
        var dStream = new DataStream(bitmaplock.Data.DataPointer, bitmaplock.Stride * bitmaplock.Size.Height, true, true);
        var buffer = new byte[bitmaplock.Stride * bitmaplock.Size.Height];
        dStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: WPF is not WINRT. WPF is .Net. WINRT is not .Net.

Comment: I suppose he meant WinRT/XAML - Jupiter

Comment: ah yes of course, corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I run in the same issue, i need acces to the raw texture data for phisics

```
DataStream dataStream = new DataStream(source.Size.Height * source.Size.Width, true, true);
bitmapSource.CopyPixels( source.Size.Width * sizeof(uint), dataStream);
var data = dataStream.ReadRange<uint>(source.Size.Width * source.Size.Height);
```

on the forums [SharpDX forumsformore details](http://www.sharpdx.com/forum/5-api-usage/650-uint-data-for-farseerphysics-texture-to-polygon)